# In pandas how to read csv files with lists in a column?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file in which some columns which look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[['ID1','ID2','ID3'],['ID1','ID4'],[]],'b':[[8.6,1.3,2.5],[7.5,1.2],[]],'c':[[12,23,79],[42,10],[]]})

Out[1]:     a               b                c
        0   [ID1, ID2, ID3] [8.6, 1.3, 2.5] [12, 23, 79]
        1   [ID1, ID4]      [7.5, 1.2]      [42, 10]
        2   []              []              []
```

The thing is that when I read it, with `pandas.read_csv`, Python considers those columns as strings. Is there a way to pass as option that it is a list of numbers within those columns? (maybe some `dtype = something`)

PS: I can do a list comprehension with `ast.literal_eval` afterwards, but it takes a while, so I'd rather have it as soon as I read the csv.

PS2: the original csv file is 600 000 lines long (which is why it takes some time to `literal_eval`. Its columns contain :

```
'ID of the project'  'postcode'    'city'       'len of the lists in the last 3 columns'  'ids of other projects'   'distance from initial project'  'jetlag from initial project'
 object                int          string       int                                       list of strings           list of floats                   list of ints
```

Comment: Could you show to original csv file to parse?

Comment: I've added the way the original csv files is. Note that the length of the lists in the 3 last columns is the same (but differs from one row to another).

Comment: so, from you PS2 edit, I assume that you csv really contains the squared brackets around the lists, correct?

Comment: @ysearka its less about providing information to facilitate understanding and more about you facilitating others to help answer your question.  I typically pass on questions that I can't answer quickly.  This requires someone to make up data.  They'll will probably not capture some nuance of your data.  This leads to wasted time.  Most answerers will pass.

Comment: Yes, if i try to print the value in onz of the cells, i get something like this: `u'[8.6, 7.6, 7.7]'`

Comment: then ast.literal_eval is the only pythonic way to do it

Comment: @piRSquared if it is to reproduct the same case, it's not long from what I gave. Copy the line creating the dataframe, then to_csv, and read_csv and you have the problem reproducted. That is why I've created this simplified dataframe

Comment: @Apero too bad then, thanks for answering!

Comment: We should not have to copy / paste and so on, your question should be clear enough for us to want to help the best we can ;-)  Next time, make sure to post a fake csv file with 2 to 3 lines at least, not explanations of what each line might contain ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can make use of the `converters` in the `pd.read_csv` function ([Documentation for read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

Using your example,

```
'ID of the project'  'postcode'    'city'       'len of the lists in the last 3 columns'  'ids of other projects'   'distance from initial project'  'jetlag from initial project'
 object                int          string       int                                       list of strings           list of floats                   list of ints
```

it could be done in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
generic = lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
conv = {'ids of other projects': generic,
        'distance from initial project': generic,
        'jetlag from initial project': generic}

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', converters=conv)
```

You would have to define for which columns to use your conversion, but this should not be a problem in your case.

The converter function will be applied during your csv import, and if your file gets too large, you can always read the csv in chunks.

Comment: It indeed helps getting the right type when reading, but using lambda is even slightly slower than a list comprehension afterwards (I've tested it).

Comment: So you mean doing this using `converters` is slower than reading without, and then do a list comprehension on the final column? Using `df.apply`? If speed is really such an issue, you might consider using a different format for the raw data, which can handle lists (most sql variants do)

Comment: It's using list comprehension not apply: `df['list_distances'] = [np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)) for x in df['list_distances']]` but indeed it yields the same result. Ok thank you, I'll turn to sql bases then.

Comment: If you didn't do so far, you could try `df.apply` as well, but it might just be one of those problems where you can't gain much.

Comment: It may be faster (and safer, but it depends on how trustworthy the data source is) to use custom parsing instead of `eval`: `re_float_g=r'(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'; lambda x: tuple(float(s_fl) for s_fl in re.match('\['+', '.join(re_float_g for _ in range(3))+'\]',x).groups())`.

Comment: The code in [c63436175](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994791/in-pandas-how-to-read-csv-files-with-lists-in-a-column#comment63436175_37995412) is `55.4 us` vs `128 us` for `eval` on my machine.