# Python - Using Pandas to eliminated curly brackets and output floats

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

Having this large csv data set, that essentially has x and y values in each column.

```
"{733.15, 179.5}",
"{565.5, 642.5}",
"{172.5, 375.5}",
"{223.5, 554.5}",....

...., 
"{213.5, 666.5}",
"{851.5, 323.5}",
"{498.5, 638.5}",
"{763.5, 102.5}"
```

or by a table,

[image]

A column is essentially this set and I can call each pair by indexing.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

brown = pd.read_csv('BrownM.csv',delimiter=',', header=None)

print brown[0]
```

this essentially calls the row above

```
print brown[0][0]
```

returns `{733.15, 179.5}`

but when wanting to select a value in this set,

```
   print brown[0][0][1]
```

returns `7`

It's treating this data set as a string, when I want it to return floats when called upon.

Also, is their a way to pass the file to where the curly brackets are eliminated?

Comment: I think you might have the same problem as me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994791/in-pandas-how-to-read-csv-files-with-lists-in-a-column Read the comments, there is `literal_eval` that can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
def str2coords(df, col, new_cols):
    df[new_cols] = df[col].str.extract(r'\{([\d\.]+),\s*([\d\.]+)\}', expand=True).astype(np.float64)
    return df.drop(col, axis=1)

In [204]: df
Out[204]:
            coord1         coord2
0  {733.15, 179.5}  {33.15, 79.5}
1   {565.5, 642.5}  {65.5, 42.5}
2   {172.5, 375.5}  {72.5, 75.5}
3   {223.5, 554.5}  {23.5, 54.5}
4   {213.5, 666.5}  {13.5, 66.5}
5   {851.5, 323.5}  {51.5, 23.5}
6   {498.5, 638.5}  {98.5, 38.5}
7   {763.5, 102.5}  {63.5, 02.5}

In [205]: df = str2coords(df, 'coord1', ['x1','y1'])

In [206]: df = str2coords(df, 'coord2', ['x2','y2'])

In [207]: df
Out[207]:
       x1     y1     x2    y2
0  733.15  179.5  33.15  79.5
1  565.50  642.5  65.50  42.5
2  172.50  375.5  72.50  75.5
3  223.50  554.5  23.50  54.5
4  213.50  666.5  13.50  66.5
5  851.50  323.5  51.50  23.5
6  498.50  638.5  98.50  38.5
7  763.50  102.5  63.50   2.5

In [208]: df.dtypes
Out[208]:
x1    float64
y1    float64
x2    float64
y2    float64
dtype: object
```

you can parse your coordinates into separate columns, using [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function:

```
In [155]: df[['x','y']] = df.coord.str.extract(r'\{([\d\.]+),\s*([\d\.]+)\}', expand=True)

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
             coord       x      y
0  {733.15, 179.5}  733.15  179.5
1   {565.5, 642.5}   565.5  642.5
2   {172.5, 375.5}   172.5  375.5
3   {223.5, 554.5}   223.5  554.5
4   {213.5, 666.5}   213.5  666.5
5   {851.5, 323.5}   851.5  323.5
6   {498.5, 638.5}   498.5  638.5
7   {763.5, 102.5}   763.5  102.5
```

Comment: I've edited my post to where i've included the table. The same should apply correct?

Comment: @DarthLazar, please check "UPDATE"

Answer (score 3):

Or you can `extract` then `split`.

```
df.col1.str.extract(r'{(.*)}', expand=False).str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

---

#### Timing

MaxU's solution is quicker as it does more in one step as opposed to mine that takes two steps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex against the string, then parse it to a float.

```
import re

# Returns 733.15
float(re.match(r'\{(.*),\s*(.*)\}', '{733.15, 179.5}').group(1))

# Returns 179.5
float(re.match(r'\{(.*),\s*(.*)\}', '{733.15, 179.5}').group(2))
```